# PHP stream socket too many TIME_WAIT after close

Tags: php, sockets

I'm using phpws (https://github.com/Devristo/phpws) to implement WebSocket.

I found out that 
after client disconnects, there are still some TCP ports in use which have the *TIME_WAIT* state,
and after a while, these ports will be released.

I've read a thread stating that I can use `socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, array('l_onoff' => 1, 'l_linger' => 1))` to prevent the *TIME_WAIT* state and close those ports immediately,
but phpws uses `stream_socket_server()`, it doesn't accept that option.

Does anybody know how to achieve the same for 'stream_socket' ?

Answer (score 0):

For another person with the same problem.. here is the solution..

```
$linger = array ('l_linger' => 0, 'l_onoff' => 1);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $linger);
socket_close($socket);
```

you can see it working with (tw value for the TCP entry):
watch -n1 cat /proc/net/sockstat
or
netstat -n | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l